# How do I store a ForeignKey list in a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I am building a platform where the user can *buy* players (like in fantasy leagues). So I have 4 models as such :

```
POSITION_CHOICES = ((1,'1'),
                    (2,'2'),
                    (3,'3'),
                    (4,'4'),
                    (5,'5'),
)

class Team(models.Model):
    ...

class Player(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True, ...)
    position = MultiSelectField(
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    player1 = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='+', blank=True,null=True,
                                limit_choices_to={'position__icontains':1},...)
    player2 = ...
    player3 = ...
    player4 = ...
    player5 = ...
    ...

class FantasyTeams(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    team1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name='Team', blank=True, null=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...
```

Basically a `Team` contains 0 or more `Players`. Both `FantasyPlayers` and `FantasyTeams` are players and teams the user bought (he can buy 0 to 5 players and 0 to 1 team, but those numbers are likely to be changed).
LUTION
The current way I've done it is quite ugly even if it works. I am now looking for something neater (as I don't find this to be generic at all), something like replacing the `player#` fields by `players` which would contains a `ForeignKey` list. I am also willing to merge the 2 models, `FantasyPlayers` and `FantasyTeams`, into one which would contains a list of players (max. 5), a list of teams (max. 1) and the `ForeignKey` to its user.

I saw that *one-to-many-fields* was mentioned several times when looking at similar questions, but all it did was confusing me even more with the `OneToOneField` and the `ManyToManyField`.

Is there any direction you could give me to store a list of `ForeignKey` in a Django model ?

---

### Solution

The following is replacing the previous `FantasyPlayers` and `FantasyTeams` :

```
class FantasyTeam(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, blank=True, null=True)
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

This is now how I create and save the models (through `ModelForm`) :

```
def fantasy_create(request):
    # Handling form datas
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditFantasyTeamForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            fantasy = FantasyTeam.objects.create(user=request.user)
            for player in form.cleaned_data['players']:
                fantasy.players.add(player)
            for team in form.cleaned_data['teams']:
                fantasy.teams.add(team)
            return redirect(...)
    # Form is not submitted yet
    else:
        form = EditFantasyTeamForm()

    return render_to_response(...)


def fantasy_edit(request):
    # Fetching the FantasyTeam object
    fantasy = ...
    # Handling form datas
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditFantasyTeamForm(request.POST, instance=fantasy)
        if form.isLUTION_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect(...)
    # Form not submitted yet
    else:
        form = EditFantasyTeamForm(instance=fantasy)

    return render_to_response(...)choices=POSITION_CHOICES, max_length=10)
    ...

class FantasyPlayers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    player1 = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='+', blank=True,null=True,
                                limit_choices_to={'position__icontains':1},...)
    player2 = ...
    player3 = ...
    player4 = ...
    player5 = ...
    ...

class FantasyTeams(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    team1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name='Team', blank=True, null=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ...
```

Basically a `Team` contains 0 or more `Players`. Both `FantasyPlayers` and `FantasyTeams` are players and teams the user bought (he can buy 0 to 5 players and 0 to 1 team, but those numbers are likely to be changed).
LUTION
The current way I've done it is quite ugly even if it works. I am now looking for something neater (as I don't find this to be generic at all), something like replacing the `player#` fields by `players` which would contains a `ForeignKey` list. I am also willing to merge the 2 models, `FantasyPlayers` and `FantasyTeams`, into one which would contains a list of players (max. 5), a list of teams (max. 1) and the `ForeignKey` to its user.

I saw that *one-to-many-fields* was mentioned several times when looking at similar questions, but all it did was confusing me even more with the `OneToOneField` and the `ManyToManyField`.

Is there any direction you could give me to store a list of `ForeignKey` in a Django model ?

---

### Solution

The following is replacing the previous `FantasyPlayers` and `FantasyTeams` :

```
class FantasyTeam(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, blank=True, null=True)
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

This is now how I create and save the models (through `ModelForm`) :

```
def fantasy_create(request):
    # Handling form datas
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditFantasyTeamForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            fantasy = FantasyTeam.objects.create(user=request.user)
            for player in form.cleaned_data['players']:
                fantasy.players.add(player)
            for team in form.cleaned_data['teams']:
                fantasy.teams.add(team)
            return redirect(...)
    # Form is not submitted yet
    else:
        form = EditFantasyTeamForm()

    return render_to_response(...)


def fantasy_edit(request):
    # Fetching the FantasyTeam object
    fantasy = ...
    # Handling form datas
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditFantasyTeamForm(request.POST, instance=fantasy)
        if form.isLUTION_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect(...)
    # Form not submitted yet
    else:
        form = EditFantasyTeamForm(instance=fantasy)

    return render_to_response(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution? (I'm not sure `ManyToManyField` is the best option.)

```
class FantasyPlayer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    position = models.MultiSelectField(choices=POSITION_CHOICES, max_length=10)

# To get a list of players
user_fantasy_players = user.fantasyplayer_set.all()
```

One disadvantage of it is inability use `limit_choices_to` to only allow selecting `Player` with matching position when editing `FantasyPlayer` (as in your example), but this could be solved in another way. Having more elegant and sane data architecture is more important in the long run, IMO.

Comment: I don't see how this could help me. I will still need to find a way to gather multiple `FantasyPlayer` (of yours) under each user, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: But doesn't user.fantasyplayer_set.all() deal with that?

Comment: OK, I now understand what you did, indeed that could work. I am now thinking which way I will adopt since a `User` can only buy 5 players of distinct position and team.

Comment: It's possible (and arguably may be better) to enforce this limitation not on data structure level. For example, in a function that implements buying new players, you can check how many players with given position and team user already has before creating new `FantasyPlayer` object.

Comment: Precisely, I came up with this. Thanks for your commitment, I was a little lazy regarding updating the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `ManyToManyField`

```
players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, ...)
```

But this is ok only if a `Player` instance can belong to several `FantasyPlayers` instances (same thing for `Team`) if a `Player` instance can only belong to one `FantasyPlayers` instance you should inverse the relationship and put a `ForeignKey` field to `FantasyPlayers` in the `Player` model and then you can use the `related_field` to access the list of `Player` instances from a `FantasyPlayers` instance.

Comment: Thanks that looks like what I'm looking for. However while creating the model through a `ModelForm` I can't save the players I selected with the form : `FantasyTeam.objects.create(...,players=form.cleaned_data['players'])` won't allow me to properly save the object as `cleaned_data` can't fetch the right thing.

Comment: Good, I got it to work. Put my solution in the question, thanks anyway.